# Getting "CSS & jQuery UI" after -> jQuery load (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, reload

I have a page with jQuery UI, working fine. Within this page I change the content of some div containers with jquery.load(), works fine too. But if the content which I load uses jQuery UI by itself (to show a accordion or a dialog as an example), I need to load the jQuery .js files and the css file again in the div container. Else it won't work :(

What can I do to not load the files again AND having a working ui-dialog, ui-accordion, ui-buttons, ... in the reloaded div?

Hope you understand what I wanted to tell :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI relies on the jQuery framework. You cannot have jQuery UI embedded in a page without having jQuery itself as well.

Answer (score 0):

when you use jquery ui buttons for example you initialize them trough a certain call like this:

```
$( ".button" ).button({ parameters });
```

now, lets say you load a big piece of your page trough ajax load, jquery.load() or any other means (for all i know you could be manually creating new DOM nodes on the fly after certain button clicks)

the only thing you would do here is wrap your piece of code in a function

```
function initializeButtons(container){
    container = (typeof(container)==="undefined") ? $('body') : container;
    $( '.button', container ).button({ parameters });
}
```

and wherever you have an ajax load you can call this function in your callback. like so:

```
$('#mydiv').load("/mypath/mydata.html", function(){
    // content is loaded, now init the buttons
    initializeButtons($('#mydiv'));
});
```

now do the same with all elements of jquery ui you use,  datepickers, accordions, buttons or other...

please keep in mind, that this is a very basic idea, for more flexibility you can add other features, in order not to initialize `.button();` on the same element twice you could add some sort of test for that too, and many other things, but this is just the basic idea of it.

Comment: nice idea! thanks! that means, if i made a function initializeAll() and put in all jquery ui stuff, and call it each time i use a .load() i wont need to load jquery files again?! :) i like!

Comment: this is technically nor really jquery stuff, it's basic javascript, the concept of functions if you are not familiar with it, is something you really should explore, as it helps you do much more than what we did here (which is basically just reusing code)